# Set default colors of line graph in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there a way to set the default colors of the lines and points in line graphs in  Illustrator CS 5? I'm having to create 75+ line graphs and it would be nice to have the colors default to my settings rather than having to recolor the lines and points every time.

Comment: There's a really clunky and hard to use 'graph design' feature that sort-of does this (see ['re-use' right at the bottom here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS3f28b00cc50711d9fc86fa8133b3ce158e-8000.html)) - but personally I find it much easier to just copy and paste existing graphs then edit their data.

Comment: Yes, the way I'm using it is creating the graph.
1) Selecting just the data points and lines
2) Copy and paste them 
3) Changing the data points and lines to my colors.

Comment: I don't think there's anything more than what user568458 has commented.

Comment: @user568458: How about making your answer an answer, rather than a comment, so it can be accepted? :)